# The guidelines on referencing are inconsistent with the example

Tags: discussion

The guidelines on referencing are inconsistent with the example.

https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing says:

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Money Stack Exchange) make sure you do
>   all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

but the example adds one more condition:

> [other sources, quotes, explanations, etc. necessary to complete the answer]

Comment: Are you aware that this help page is identical on every SE site? [Here it is on softwarerecs.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) Perhaps this question belongs on meta.SE.

Comment: @BenMiller I wasn't aware of that. Then it indeed would have made more sense to ask  on  meta.SE. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Help page you cite, the formatting can stand some improvement, but guideline itself is quite consistent.

If I can paraphrase -

---

This is the quote from the website (linked) that nicely addresses this question.

> These words are the text of the quote itself. A few sentences.

Last, some further thoughts of my own regarding how the quote sufficiently answers the question.

---

The 3 bullet points are suggestions for the quote process itself, the example adds the line that makes it a good answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification!